# Выборка из MySQL при отсутствующем результате в подзапросе

Tags: mysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  `categories`,
  `clients`,
  `deals`,
  `orders`,
  `stuff`,
  `statuslist`,
  `user`
WHERE
  `deals`.`deals_statusid` = '1' AND 
  `clients`.`clients_id` = `deals`.`deals_clientid` AND 
  `stuff`.`stuff_id` = orders.`orders_stuffid` AND 
  `orders`.`orders_dealid` = `deals`.`deals_id` AND 
  `statuslist`.`statuslist_id` = `deals`.`deals_statusid` AND 
  `categories`.`categories_id` = `stuff`.`stuff_catid` AND 
  `user`.`user_id` = `deals`.`deals_managerid`
GROUP BY
  deals_id
```

Таблица orders пуста, как следствие, весь запрос возвращает 0 строк. Пробовал использовать COALESCE(orders.`orders_stuffid`, '1'), тоже ничего не выходит. Получается, что из-за отсутствия информации о составе заказа, я не могу получить информацию о всей сделке. С этим можно что-нибудь сделать?

Comment: Можно использовать join'ы, вместо перечисления в from, например left join.

Comment: Я не очень сильно разбираюсь в Sql, но мне кажется конструкция моего запроса схожа с join'ами. join также вернет пустой результат ON `stuff`.`stuff_id` = orders.`orders_stuffid` и результат будет таким же. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: *мне кажется конструкция моего запроса схожа с join'ами.* А конкретно - это иная форма INNER JOIN - который тут неприменим.

Comment: Как быть? Использовать LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Да, во всем запросе все запятые заменить на join, перенести условия соединения в них и сделать left join с таблицей, в которой могут отсутствовать записи. left именно для этого и предназначен